# How to solve "boost::bad_any_cast: failed conversion using boost::any_cast" when using boost program options?

Tags: c++, boost, types, casting, boost-program-options

```
//Using boost program options to read command line and config file data
    #include <boost/program_options.hpp>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;
    namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    po::options_description config("Configuration");
    config.add_options()
                ("IPAddress,i","IP Address")
                ("Port,p","Port")
                 ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, config),vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    cout << "Values\n";

    string address = (vm["IPAddress"].as<std::string >()).c_str();
    string port = (vm["Port"].as<std::string>()).c_str();

    cout << (vm["IPAddress"].as< string >()).c_str();
    cout << " " << (vm["Port"].as<string>()).c_str();

    return 0;

}
```

Are the inputted values somehow unprintable?

Here is gdb output, seems to be be cast problem:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl
>
> > '
> >                   what():  boost::bad_any_cast: failed conversion using boost::any_cast
>
> ```
>         Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
>         0x0000003afd835935 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
> ```

```
string address = (vm["IPAddress"].as<std::string >()).c_str();
```

is where the error occurs; I have tried std::string and string with the same results.

```
testboostpo -i 192.168.1.10 -p 5000
```

is the command line.

I tried declaring the types, like so:

```
config.add_options()
        ("IPAddress,i", po::value<std::string>(), "IP Address")
            ("Port,p", po::value<std::string>(), "Port");
```

but the error still occurred.

Could this be a genuine bug?

Comment: Please post the command line arguments you're passing to the program.

Comment: nit: it is superfluous to convert the result from `std::string::c_str()` to a `std::string`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You see the `boost::bad_any_cast` exception thrown from the `po::variables_map` because the two `const char*` argument overload of [`po::options_description_easy_init::operator()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/options_descri_idp44766528.html) does not specify a `po::value_semantic` type, so converting it to a `std::string` will not work. If you want to convert the value to a `std::string`, and it is required for your application, use the `required()` value semantic.

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    po::options_description config("Configuration");
    config.add_options()
                ("IPAddress,i", po::value<std::string>()->required(), "IP Address")
                ("Port,p", po::value<std::string>()->required(), "Port")
                ;

    try {
        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, config),vm);
        po::notify(vm);
        std::cout << "Values" << std::endl;

        const std::string address = vm["IPAddress"].as<std::string>();
        const std::string port = vm["Port"].as<std::string>();

        std::cout << "address: " << address << std::endl;
        std::cout << "port: " << port << std::endl;
    } catch ( const std::exception& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note the added catch block since parsing can (and will, as you have noticed) throw exceptions. Here is a sample session:

```
samm$ ./a.out
the option '--IPAddress' is required but missing
samm$ ./a.out --IPAddress 127.0.0.1
the option '--Port' is required but missing
samm$ ./a.out --IPAddress 127.0.0.1 --Port 5000
Values
address: 127.0.0.1
port: 5000
samm$
```

Here is an [online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=da8370546903b0df9f5427dc83c0257b-17035df9b4df11bb8fd30b8fc89ee5d1) showing the same behavior, courtesy of COmpile LInk RUn (coliru).

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare the ip-address and port as strings when you add the options:

```
config.add_options()
    ("IPAddress,i", po::value<std::string>(), "IP Address")
    ("Port,p", po::value<std::string>(), "Port")
    ;
```

Comment: partially correct, a `boost::bad_any_cast` exception [will still be thrown](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f50049b76d804061b926500aa6953033-57c67fe4b82106f02cd504259a9a9be3) when casting an option that is not present in the `po::variables_map` to a `std::string`.

Comment: Yes but that is because of the unfortunate usage of the `operator[]` which inserts an element if given key does not exists. The inserted element is an empty `boost::any` which obviously can't be `any_caste`-ed. Using `at` or `find` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

This same message can also occur if you are not handling optional arguments correctly.

Sam's solution nails required arguments and the OP's code suggests required - just mark them required.  For optional inputs, [the Boost PO tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#idp337609360) gives us a template for checking if the option exists before converting it:

```
if(vm.count("address")) 
{
    const std::string address = vm["IPAddress"].as<std::string>();
    std::cout << "address: " << address << std::endl;
}
if(vm.count("port")) 
    const std::string port = vm["Port"].as<std::string>();
    std::cout << "port: " << port << std::endl;
}
```

My problem - I had copied/pasted and forgotten to align the if test with the usage!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error message, but it was because I was using the shorthand `i`, instead of `IPAddress`.

```
// this throws the cast exception
const std::string address = vm["i"].as<std::string>();
// this does not
const std::string address = vm["IPAddress"].as<std::string>();
```

Boost takes the first one declared. So if your option is declared as `IPAddress,i` you need to use `vm["IPAddres"]`, while `i,IPAddress` you need to use `vm["i"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the same problem as this guy had but here's something that caught me:

If you put your type in an anonymous namespace, there will be two classes with the same name but different instances and the casting will fail.  For example:

a.hpp:

```
namespace {
class MyClass {...};
}
```

b.cpp:

```
#include "a.hpp"
cli_options.add_options()("test", po::value<MyClass>(), "test desc");
```

c.cpp:

```
#include "a.hpp" // THIS WILL MAKE A DIFFERENT "MyClass"
vm["test"].as<MyClass>();  // Fails at runtime.
```

It fails because the `MyClass` in `b.cpp` and the one in `c.cpp` aren't the same class.  Because of the anonymous namespace.

Removing the anonymous namespace solves the problem.