# boost:bad_any_cast: failed conversion using boost:any_cast error

Tags: c++, vector, boost-program-options

Running into an issue with Boost Program Options. I added a multiple use option let's call it "--opt".   When I run the program.exe from the command line with two "--opt" I get the following error from boost.

> terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >: boost::bad_any_cast: failed conversion using boost::any_cast

I am unsure what exactly is causing boost::bad_any_cast.  I am a novice when it comes to C++ and Boost.   Below is an example of the code I am using and where I think the boost::bad_any_cast might be occurring.  The error only appeared after I added the `std::vector`.   Any thoughts what could be the issue?  Or any resources to point me so I could figure it out on my own too?

```
po::value<std::vector<std::string>>()
```

I am well aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535180/how-to-solve-boostbad-any-cast-failed-conversion-using-boostany-cast-when) previous question as well.

Answer (score 0):

try to add ->required() after the cast :
po::value>()->required()